# Parse and transform JSON Objects to an html table using AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, symfony, symfony-3.3

I am using SYMFONY 3 and i want to parse a received JSON from controller using Ajax , the issue there that the JSON can't be read properly and returns undefined this is my code below :

Controller :

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $RAW_QUERY = 'SELECT id,DO_Date,DL_Design,DL_Qte,DL_MontantHT,DL_MontantTTC FROM `facture_ligne` WHERE facture_id=:id';

            $statement = $em->getConnection()->prepare($RAW_QUERY);
            // Set parameters
            $statement->bindValue('id', $id);
            $statement->execute();

            $facture = $statement->fetchAll();

            $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
            $reports = $serializer->serialize($facture,'json');
            return new Response($reports);
```

My script in a the twig file :

```
function detailfacture{{ fact.id }} (id) {

    var z= new XMLHttpRequest();
    z.open("get","{{ path('Ajaxonify',{'id':fact.id}) }})",true);
    z.send()
    z.onreadystatechange = function result () {
        var json=z.responseText;
        if(json!="")
        {
            alert(json);

            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + json[1].DL_MontantHT + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[1].DO_Date + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[1].DL_Qte + "</td>");
                $('#tb').append(tr);
            }  
        }
        else alert("helo");    
    }
}
```

And this some screen shots of the results :
[image]
[image]

I just tested with a static JSON and it works fine

This is what

```
console.log(data);
console.log(json);
```

returns

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON into a JavaScript object before using it, like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(json);
```

Insert this line after `alert(json)` but before the `for` loop, so your script looks like this:

```
function detailfacture{{ fact.id }} (id) {

    var z= new XMLHttpRequest();
    z.open("get","{{ path('Ajaxonify',{'id':fact.id}) }})",true);
    z.send()
    z.onreadystatechange = function result () {
        var json=z.responseText;
        if(json!="")
        {
            alert(json);
            json = JSON.parse(json);

            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DL_MontantHT + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DO_Date + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DL_Qte + "</td>");
                $('#tb').append(tr);
            }  
        }
        else alert("helo");    
    }
}
```

Comment: the alert returns [object][object] i just tested before , the json is already parsed in controller

Comment: I updated my answer with the full example. If the `alert` show JSON text, the JSON hasn't been parsed yet and is not an object.

Comment: Also, please note that I updated the lines with `tr.append()` calls to use the `i` variable instead of a hardcoded `1`.

Comment: Is not that easy the problem is not with the i or with the json parse i just have tested this before posting

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the json is already parsed in the controller". I can see by your screenshots that immediately before the for loop starts, the JSON _has not yet been parsed._ Please test my full example again.

Comment: Thank you i was a pretty missed up , your code work , but seriously i did not know how

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read the JSON, there is a lot of plugins Like [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en). To use it, just output the JSON and the plugin will identify and activate, formatting JSON for easy reading.

Another answer is pretty print JSON:

PHP: `$echo "<pre>".json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>";`

JS: `document.write(JSON.stringify(data, null,4));`

Comment: i can read it look to the screen shot, i just want to transform it into an html table

Comment: The problem is Tables have an patern (Col, Cel) and json can be an data tree like XML. Only knowing the JSON response to output it. My answer let you read it in a organized way

Comment: I know it but just did not know why it returns undefined : take a look to this example that i follow it    http://jsfiddle.net/8kkg3/

Comment: Is undefined because it is a string, not an JS object, you need to do `var json = JSON.parse(z.responseText);`

Comment: the json.parse retruns  [object][object] the json is already parsed in the controller

Comment: do console.log(data) and see the output in the console. You will see what is inside the Object. show a print on the question

Comment: just added to the post

Comment: Your data variable is an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for help i just fixed the issue by jason answer thank you for you time